# Create backend Address pool for basic load balancer azure arm template

Tags: azure, load-balance

I'm attempting to create a backend address pool via an ARM template for a load balancer with the following code:

```
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools",
        "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
        "name": "[concat(variables('engineLbName'), '/LoadBalancerBEAddressPool')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('engineLbName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {}
```

The loadbalancer it is targetting is using a basic SKU. When i attempt to deploy this arm template through the azure portal, I am given the following error message:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BackendOperationOnlyAllowedForStandardLB",
    "message": "Operation on backend pool /subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/*******/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/LB-engine/backendAddressPools/LoadBalancerBEAddressPool not allowed. This operation is only allowed for standard SKU load balancers.",
    "details": []
}
```

}

Obviously, this indicates that i need to make my LB/LBIP of a standard SKU, however i specifically need this done on a basic SKU.

I am very confused as to why this error occurs, as we have many basic LB's that have backend configuration, and you are freely able to create a BE pool through the portal on a basic LB - I am unsure on how to do this via an ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I downloaded the Template from Azure which effectively had my Load Balancer's Backend Address Pool as a "dependsOn" and as a "property".

This is under the load balancer's "dependsOn" list :

```
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', 'LB-db-phi-dbphipri', 'LoadBalancerBEAddressPool')]"
```

And the property under the Load Balancer's property list:

```
    "backendAddressPools": [
      {
        "name": "LoadBalancerBEAddressPool",            
        "properties": {}
      }
    ]
```

Lastly, I had a child definition of the backendAddressPool as well

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools",
  "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
  "name": "LB-db-phi-dbphipri/LoadBalancerBEAddressPool",
  "properties": {}
}
```

You don't need both. In my case I removed the "child" and the "dependsOn" and just have the property defined under the load balancer.